# Panel Dataset and Correlation - Stata

Tags: stata, panel, pearson-correlation

I have a panel dataset and I am having trouble using the correlation command to get the correlation between variables. Can anyone provide a code for Pearson goodness of fit correlation with a panel dataset?

Comment: It's just `correlate` followed by a list of variable names, except that that lumps panels together. Was there something different you wanted?

Comment: The term _goodness of fit_ does not really belong with _Pearson correlation_.

Comment: Other way round, there is nothing here on your data, the code you tried or what trouble you are experiencing.